# Validate Form Initially When User Starts Typing

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using this [jQuery plugin](http://www.formvalidator.net) for  form validation. With the current code posted below, validation starts only after the first time lost focus/blur  event happens on an element.

However, I would like the validation to be performed initially when user starts typing.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.validate({"form" : "#testForm"});
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/theme-default.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="testForm">
<p>
Email
<input name="email" data-validation="email">
</p>
<p>
Username
<input name="user" data-validation="length alphanumeric" 
 data-validation-length="3-12" 
 data-validation-error-msg="User name has to be an alphanumeric value (3-12 chars)">
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `keyup` to trigger validations when user starts typing:

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
  $(this).validate();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validate({
    "form": "#testForm"
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/theme-default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <form id="testForm">
    <p>
      Email
      <input name="email" data-validation="email">
    </p>
    <p>
      Username
      <input name="user" data-validation="length alphanumeric" data-validation-length="3-12" data-validation-error-msg="User name has to be an alphanumeric value (3-12 chars)">
    </p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please remove `$('input').validate();` and then I'll accept this as answer. I guess because of that statement, validation happens even before user starts typing.

Comment: Code has been updated. You can have a look. You can up-vote and mark it as done. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

script:- use validateOnEvent

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.validate({"form" : "#testForm","validateOnEvent":true});
});
```

form:-

```
<form id="testForm">
<p>
Email
<input name="email" data-validation="email" data-validation-event="keypress"> // data-validation-event is used for event base elements
</p>
<p>
Username
<input name="user" data-validation="length alphanumeric" 
 data-validation-length="3-12" 
 data-validation-error-msg="User name has to be an alphanumeric value (3-12 chars)" data-validation-event="keypress">
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works. Unfortunately, I've accepted another post as answer.